# Spring: Adding Transaction Specific Resource

Tags: java, spring, spring-transactions, aspects

I am trying to find a way to add/get a resource/state to an existing transaction. Is this possible in Spring?

What I'm trying to achieve is similar to the pseudo code below:

```
@Service
@Transactional("txManager")
public class ServiceImpl implements Service {

    @Override
    @AddResourceHere
    public TestObj doSomething(){
        ...
    }

    @Override
    @AddResourceHere
    public TestObj doSomethingAgain(){
        ...
    }
}

@Aspect
@Component
public class Interceptor {

    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.get(Interceptor.class);

    @Before("@annotation(my.package.AddResourceHere)")
    public void switchDatabase(JoinPoint joinPoint){
        MyResource resource = TransactionResouceAdder.getResource("transactionSpecificResource");
        if(resource == null){
            TransactionResouceAdder.addResource(new MyResource("A new resource"));
            ...
        }

        else
            log.info("resource has already been added for this transaction");
    }
}

public class Test {
    ...
    @Test
    @Transactional("txManager")
    public void doSomethingTest(){
        serviceImpl.doSomething();
        serviceImpl.doSomethingAgain();
    }
}
```

I found something similar

```
org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationManager#getResouce(Object)
org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationManager#bindResource(Object, Object)
```

However, this adds a resource to the current thread of the transaction. Is there a way to make the resource transaction bounded only?

In my actual code, I am using spring jdbc's DataSourceTransactionManager as the transaction manager.

Thanks in advance for any help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`TransactionSynchronizationManager` was designed for this purpose and resources are cleared at the end of a transaction (see [`AbstractPlatformTransactionManager`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/39eb7442fc0533dfc1429538e3a23f0ad4a5dd9b/spring-tx/src/main/java/org/springframework/transaction/support/AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java#L1048)). You'd have to hook it up to your custom annotation with an aspect, but it looks like you already know how to do that.

Comment: Thanks for the info! Actually, after digging into the source code, I found out that the way I used the TransactionSynchronizationManager is incomplete. The important step that I missed is the synchronization of the resource to the current active transaction. This step involves extending/using the following:

    **org.springframework.transaction.support.ResourceHolder**
    **org.springframework.transaction.support.ResourceHolderSupport**
**org.springframework.transaction.support.ResourceHolderSynchronization**